# WooCommerce Add custom column on order backend

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On Woocommerce backend I want to add a column with a gray flag icon and when clicked it will change to red. I know it can be done using jQuery, my concern is how to store the css styling so that when the admin re-visit the backend the current changes color of the flag will remain as is even if it is reload or refresh.

Please help.

Thanks,
JM

Comment: On the click event, you will need to call an ajax function which will store the corresponding setting/value in the database and that setting/value should load along with the record while loading it.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

But how to store data from custom column I created?

Comment: Can you post the code for the custom column that you have created?